# Python matplotlib scientific axis formating

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, formatting, axes

I've edited my question, I believe it is more didactic that way,

I'm plotting a chart using matplotlib and I'm facing issues with the formatting of the axes. I can't figure out how to force him to use the same scientific formatting all the time : In the bellow example, e4 (instead of e4 and e2). Also I would like to have always two decimals - 
Any idea ? the doc on that is not very extensive.

Creating a random df of data :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.stats.api import ols
import pandas as pd

mu, sigma = 100, 15
x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(100000)
y = x *100 + (np.random.randn()*100)
```

Calculating the linear regression :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x,'y':y})
res = ols(y=df['y'], x=df['x'])
df['yhat'] = df['x']*res.beta[0] + res.beta[1]
```

Plotting :

```
plt.scatter(df['x'], df['y'])  
plt.plot(df['x'], df['yhat'], color='red') 
plt.title('Scatter graph with linear regression')              
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', scilimits=(0,0))
plt.ylim(0)
plt.xlim(0)
```

Please find the output [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuTSg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, matplotlib does not offer exactly this options out of the box. The documentation is indeed sparse ([Ticker API](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html) is the place to go). The Formatter classes are responsible for formatting the tick values. Out of the ones offered, only [ScalarFormatter](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter) (the default formatter) offers scientific formatting, however, it does not allow the exponent or number of significant digits to be fixed. One alternative would be to use either `FixedFormatter` or `FuncFormatter`, which essentially allow you to freely choose the tick values (the former can be indirectly selected using 
`plt.gca().set_xticklabels`). However, none of them allow you to choose the so called `offset_string` which is the string displayed at the end of the axis, customary used for a value offset, but `ScalarFormatter` also uses it for the scientific multiplier.

Thus, my best solution consists of a custom formatter derived from `ScalarFormatter`, where instead of autodetecting order of magnitude and format string, those are just fixed by the used:

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
import matplotlib.ticker

if 'axes.formatter.useoffset' in rcParams:
    # None triggers use of the rcParams value
    useoffsetdefault = None
else:
    # None would raise an exception
    useoffsetdefault = True

class FixedScalarFormatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter):
    def __init__(self, format, orderOfMagnitude=0, useOffset=useoffsetdefault, useMathText=None, useLocale=None):
        super(FixedScalarFormatter,self).__init__(useOffset=useOffset,useMathText=useMathText,useLocale=useLocale)
        self.base_format = format
        self.orderOfMagnitude = orderOfMagnitude

    def _set_orderOfMagnitude(self, range):
        """ Set orderOfMagnitude to best describe the specified data range.

        Does nothing except from preventing the parent class to do something.
        """
        pass

    def _set_format(self, vmin, vmax):
        """ Calculates the most appropriate format string for the range (vmin, vmax).

        We're actually just using a fixed format string.
        """
        self.format = self.base_format
        if self._usetex:
            self.format = '$%s$' % self.format
        elif self._useMathText:
            self.format = '$\mathdefault{%s}$' % self.format
```

Note that the default value of `ScalarFormatter`'s constructor parameter `useOffset` changed at some point, mine tries to guess which one is the right one.

Attach this class to one or both axes of your plots as follows:

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(FixedScalarFormatter('%.2f',4))
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(FixedScalarFormatter('%.2f',4))
```

Comment: nice -- although shouldn't it emit at least a warning when the values are outside the range that this easily fits?

Comment: Should it? You choose the format string, if you want to have 1e6 printed with 4 digits after the decimal (i.e. 10 significant digits), then that's what you get :). Seriously: That would involve parsing the format string, not completely trivial. If you write `self.format = '%.'+str(self.sigfigs)+'f'` instead of `self.base_format` (as in the original `ScalarFormatter`), then you could play some games with `sigfigs` of course.

Comment: Even when I'm writing code for myself I think "here's enough rope to hang yourself with" is suboptimal code design. Maybe especially when writing for myself. Anyway, I wasn't thinking of parsing a warning out of the format string automatically, but tuning the warning when one sets the string & other values.

Comment: Works but what an amount of lines for "such a simple thing".
I'm hesitating to simply drop my request to have two decimals and solely have the 1e6 all the time simply using 
`yy, locs = plt.yticks()  
        plt.yticks(yy, [a/1e6 for a in yy])  
        xx, locs = plt.xticks()  
        plt.xticks(xx, [a/1e6 for a in xx])`

Comment: Ah, but the two decimals is an easy thing, you use the `FormatStrFormatter i.e. `plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))`. If combined with your manual rescaling, what you'll be missing out is the `offset_string`, which goes at the end of the axes.